# asp.net mvc dynamically get img src from database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image

I am trying to show the icon/image of a model from database. In my database I have place that holds the image location as filename.png . What I have the image in my content folder of the application. But the image is not seen.

```
<tr>
                <td>Icon Location: </td>
                <td>ahmeteasi.png</td>
                <td> <img src="/Contents/ahmeteasi.png" />  </td>
            </tr>
```

In my view, I have sometihng like this.

```
        <td> <img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/Contents/{0}", Model.appIconLocation))" />  </td>
```

Even though the page source shows it right. I cannot see it. where is the problem.Thank you
[This is the error. when I click it from page source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDrO3.png)

Comment: So the image exists at this exact location on your machine, verify: D:\CETAPPSUGG - Copy\CETAPPSUGG\Contents\ahmeteasi.png ?

Comment: Are you sure it is in `/contents/` and not `/Content/Images/` ?  That is the more common path (for pre-core mvc anyways).

Comment: oh god. thank you it is Content. you are right.